# Ограничение перехода по ссылкам в UIWebView

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, webview, iphone

Стоит задача ограничить возможность ухода со страницы загруженной в UIWebView. То есть оставить возможность скролла страницы, оставить лайки-комментарии (страница фейсбука) но не покидать данную страницу. Соответственно userInteractionEnabled = NO вопрос не решает. Попробовал решение из сети:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"http://www.facebook.com/login"]) || ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"http://m.facebook.com/login"]))
    {
        return NO;
    }
return YES;
```

}

но логирование показывает что я не попадаю внутрь if'а, метод всегда возвращает YES. То есть вероятно я неправильно использую scheme или логику использования этого метода. Или может дело не в этом и вопрос можно решить иначе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не знаю поможет ли вам использование - **(BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:** решить вашу задачу, но помочь вам попасть в if могу попробовать:

Короткий ответ: попробуйте

```
request.URL.absoluteString + регулярные выражения
```

взамен вашего [[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:].

Чуть длиннее: заверните код проверки соответствия строки регулярному выражению (например matches:) куда-нибудь, скажем, в свою категорию NSString+Regex, и используйте в shouldStartLoadWithRequest:

```
[request.URL.absoluteString matches:BaseURLString]
```

Таким способом я решаю немного другие задачи, связанные с UIWebView, но вам, кажется, такое решение тоже может пригодиться.

Ну и напоследок подсказка по поводу синтаксиса:

Для селекторов, которым не передаются параметры, можно (а для свойств, объявленных с помощью @property даже рекомендуется, например, Github Objective-C conventions) использовать точку (dot-notation).

То есть в вашем случае вы используете пробел только в случае isEqual: (он принимает параметр)

Вместо

```
[[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:]
```

Лучше писать

```
[request.URL.scheme isEqual:]
```

Можно использовать обе формы, но вторая гораздо легче читается.

Comment: Stanislaw, спасибо. Возможно чуть подробнее? Это значение чему то должно присваиваться и где определяется, в смысле в каком методе?

Comment: Я поправил ответ. Достаточно подробно?

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: Я только что написал развёрнутый ответ, возможно он окажется полезным.

Comment: Добавил подсказку про синтаксис.

Comment: Регулярные выражения тут на самом деле ни к чему, вам нужно работать с `(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` — см. ответ @afiki ниже.

Answer (score 2):

используй navigationType, сравнивай его на значения UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked и прочие.